# How to pass a custom class between Activities

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I found many simple solutions to this (such as Intent.putExtra(String, String) and Bundle.putString(String, String)), but this is not helpful for my situation.

I have a class called MyMP3 which contains non-primitive types. I need to pass the following for MyMP3...

```
private AudioFile audioFile;
private Tag tag;
private int index;
private boolean saved, startedWithLyrics;
private String id3lyrics;
```

AudioFile and Tag are both classes that I imported from a .jar file. How can I go about passing these to another Activity via Intents? I tried messing with implementing Parcelable for my "MyMP3" class, but I am not sure how to correctly use these methods when not passing primitive types.

Could you help me out and look at my code below and try to tell me how to correctly use Parcelable with a custom class like mine? How do I set the Parcel in the writeToParcel function and how do I correctly retrieve the class in another Activity?

Below is my code (the part that is important, at least). I've been trying different things for a couple of days now, but I cannot get it to work. Please help me out!

```
public class MyMP3 extends AudioFile implements Parcelable
{
private AudioFile audioFile;
private Tag tag;
private int index;
private boolean saved, startedWithLyrics;
private String id3lyrics;

public MyMP3(File f, int index)
{
    this.audioFile = AudioFileIO.read(f);
    this.tag = this.audioFile.getTag();
    this.index = index;
    this.saved = false;
    this.id3lyrics = getLyrics();
}

@Override
public int describeContents()
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flats)
{
    /* This method does not work, but I do not know how else to implement it */

    Object objects[] = {this.audioFile, this.tag, this.index, this.saved, this.startedWithLyrics, this.id3lyrics};
    out.writeArray(objects);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyMP3> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyMP3>()
{
    public MyMP3 createFromParcel(Parcel in)
    {
        /* Taken from the Android Developer website */
        return new MyMP3(in);
    }

    public MyMP3[] newArray(int size)
    {
        /* Taken from the Android Developer website */
        return new MyMP3[size];
    }
};

private MyMP3(Parcel in)
{
        /* This method probable needs changed as well */
    Object objects[] = in.readArray(MyMP3.class.getClassLoader());
}
```

}

Comment: Are members of AudioFile/Tag primitive? If so, you can perhaps extend AudioFile and Tag in your project and implement parcelable for these objects which you can then use in your main project.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your MyMP3 class Parcelable like that. Make sure you get the read/write order correct. The non-primitives must also be Parcelable, so you might not have control over that unfortunately. Alternatively, you could come up with your own serialization/deserialization. You could use a text format, like JSON or XML. Another alternative is to use subclass Application (make sure you declare it in your manifest) and use it is as a place to hang objects that span Activities. This keeps the object in memory for the lifecycle of your app, so be careful with doing this.